# Emacs: how to open sunrise-cd dired navigation on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23, emacs24

I have question for how I can set sunrise-cd dired navigation to become a default buffer everytime when I startup an emacs? I have tried use M-x desktop-save but it is not worked.

One more thing is how to making the sunrise become full-screen like default dired navigation, I means making a windows calendar buffer disappear under the explorer in photo below.
Can you give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

http://www.emacswiki.org/pics/static/SunriseCommanderScreenshotOnePage.png

Answer (score 0):

To start sunrise everytime you can add `(sunrise)` to your `.emacs` file